# How do you fix Socket.io cross origin restrictions? (I've tried previous solutions)

Tags: socket.io, cors

I am having trouble with cross-origin restrictions with Socket.io with React and node.js. I have tried some of the answers that were given before, and you can see it in my code, but I'm still facing the issues.

My Client-Side React.js code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

function Messages(){

    const [response, setResponse] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = socketIOClient("http://localhost:8000", { 
            transport: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'],
            withCredentials: true 
        })
        socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
            console.log(data);
            setResponse(data)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Messages</h1>
            <p>Here: {response}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Messages
```

My node.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const port = 4001;
const socketRoutes = require("./routes/socket");

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
  
    next();
  });

app.use('/', socketRoutes);

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIo(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:8000/',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
        credentials: true
    }
}); // < Interesting!

let interval;

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("New client connected");
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  interval = setInterval(() => getApiAndEmit(socket), 1000);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
})

const getApiAndEmit = socket => {
    const response = new Date();
    // Emitting a new message. Will be consumed by the client
    socket.emit("FromAPI", response);
  };

server.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('port 8000');
})
```

By the way, everything works when I turn Cross-Origin off on Safari, but I need it to work on Chrome.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this option instead when you creating socket.io server:

```
cors : {
    origin : '*'
},
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: This helped correct the error. However, the console then said you can't use the "credential" property. So, in order for it to work, in addition to your suggestion, I had to remove "withCredentials" in React.js and "credentials" in node.js. Thank you for the help!